# Azure CosmosDB pricing - how many RTs

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is there a way to calculate how many RUs I would need if the a documentdb database is expected to have roughly 800 writes a second and 1500 reads a second?

Each read is a simple retrieve based on the index, and each item will have about 15 small data fields (a few bools, short strings, and short doubles).

Each write will be an update of most of the data values for the record.

The documentations states 1 RU = 1kb GET, well each GET in this instance should be less than 1kb I would suspect so the reads would be about 1500 RU/s but I have no idea how to calculate the writes; any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no objective way to answer this, other than you doing some benchmarking, and looking at the resulting RU's of your various queries and writes (the return header has RU cost of each operation).

Answer (score 2):

[There's a simple to use capacity planning tool available online](https://www.documentdb.com/capacityplanner). You can simply upload a sample JSON document and then specify how many reads and writes per second you expect and it will estimate your required RU/s throughput.

As David so eloquently pointed out, this should only be used as a starting point to give you a ballpark of what your minimum RU cost might be. If your primary read pattern was simply retrieving documents directly by their Id then it might be relatively accurate. In reality, RU is calculated based on the complexity of your queries. So once you have your baseline it's important to do proper analysis of your query patterns and get a feel for their RU cost.

Luckily, the ease and speed with which you can scale Cosmos in response to load is one of it's most compelling features in my opinion. In my experience, adding or removing RU throughput is done within a matter of seconds so you can definitely add a layer of intelligent database tuning within your application to optimize your cost and usage.

Comment: It's not so simple: There are point-reads ("get"), queries, and writes, each costing different RU. And without trying out specific queries, there's simply no way to know the cost. The OP has to run real queries to get a good idea of approx. RU cost. And this will change if the OP is using partitioned collections, different indexing schemes, etc.

Comment: @DavidMakogon As this tool is provided directly from MS to aid in capacity planning I think it's an important and valuable tool to use as a starting point. I've updated my answer to reflect your concerns regarding the other points you addressed.